# ASP.net link to other page with passing parameter

Tags: asp.net

my question is, how to call another aspx page from same project, with passing parameter, like ID-20?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are there so negative votes? I think this is a simple question, yet valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the source page, you can pass data with query string

```
.../target.aspx?Id=20
```

Then on target page get those values

```
String s = Request.QueryString["Id"];
```

Notice that you shouldn't pass any sensitive data by this method

Comment: Thanks, I will be passing just DB IDs.

Comment: Request isn't recognized by my visual studio 2008 asp.net, any other way to read passed parameter? Thanks.

Comment: If the intellisense doesn't recognize, doesn't mean the mean don't exist. Have you tried ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Response.Redirect( "another.aspx?id=20" );
```